# evaluating a postfix expression eg

Tags: java, arrays, string, postfix-notation, infix-notation

i am trying to evaluating a postfix expression, i can do it for characters, but tried to do it this time with numbers and not just single digits. here is my code,

```
package test;

import java.util.Stack;

public class EvaluatePostfix {

public static int solution(String postfix){

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    int val1 = 0;
    int val2 = 0;
    String[] str = postfix.split(" ");


    for(int i =0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(i))){
            stack.push(Integer.parseInt(str[i]));
            System.out.println(stack.peek());
        }
        else{
            //System.out.println(stack.peek());
            val1 = stack.pop();
            val2 = stack.pop();

            switch(str[i].charAt(0)){

            case '+':
                stack.push(val1 + val2);
                sum += val2;
                break;
            case '-':
                stack.push(val1 - val2) ;
                sum -= val2;
                break;
            case '/':
                stack.push(val1 / val2) ;
                sum /= val2;
                break;
            case '*':
                stack.push(val1 * val2) ;
                sum *= val2;
                break;
            }
            //System.out.println(sum);
        }
        //System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }

    return stack.pop();


}

public static void main(String[]args){

    String test = "10 20 30 * +";
    //solution(test);

    System.out.println(solution(test));

}

}
```

i have 10, 20 as output it doesnt outputs 30 * +

i also have an error which says the following,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at test.EvaluatePostfix.solution(EvaluatePostfix.java:18)
at test.EvaluatePostfix.main(EvaluatePostfix.java:60)
```

i dont know why i have that error, i clearly check that str[i] is a digit, * is not a digit so why does it try to convert to a digit;

Thanks

Comment: What do you understand from the exception? It's clear from the logs. can you convert `*` into `int`

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're not pushing everything onto the stack, rather than just the numbers? Your implementation is going to give you trouble if you manage to get to the end of your input string...

Comment: yes, thats why i surprises, cus my code say if(Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(i))){
            stack.push(Integer.parseInt(str[i]));}   * is not a digit so why does it count * as a digit

Comment: Let me guess: your source file is named EvaluatePostfix.java, and the `if` statement is on line 17 (the line above the line mentioned in the exception trace).  You might want to see what is in `str[i]` on that line, and then see why it got there with that value.

Comment: i am trying to evaluate the expression, so i cant push everyting into the stack, i did the same with just digits for example "123*+" this works, but now i want to try something like this "10 20 30 * +" pls if have a way of solving this let me know

Comment: @ScottHunter i did what u said, i realise now its all my fault, thanks

Comment: @ScottHunter but i am checking if the str[i] are digit, thats an if statement, why will it give an error, when its *

Comment: @user3137376: No, you are checking if a character of `postfix`, which is an array of strings, is a digit, as @dasblinkenlight (excellent name!) points out.

Comment: I have no idea what you think you're doing with the 'sum' variable, but it is neither necessary nor correct. Also your subtract and divide cases are both back to front.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking the wrong character for being a digit: this expression `postfix.charAt(i)` does not check the correct character, because the index `i` goes out of sync with the position in the original string `postfix`. Your loop uses `i` to index `str` array, so the index goes from zero to the number of tokens, not from zero to the length of the string.

Use this expression instead:

```
if(Character.isDigit(str[i].charAt(0))) {
    ...
} ...
```